# Create Widget not listed under Widget Instances

Tags: admin, widgets

I have a functioning widget that displays under Admin > CMS > Pages > Content > Add Widget, and that's great. But it also displays under Admin > CMS > Widgets > Add New Widget Instance, and I'd like it to not do so.

Is there a way to deactivate it on this page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to deactivate it from the CMS - Widget and leaving it active in the Add Widget since the widget is the same with the same properties. 
If you want to do that for a certain user you can use ACL and dont give the role access to the Widget grid.